# SQL - Identifying NULL/0 Child Records

Tags: sql, null

Good morning everyone,

I am trying to identify when a legal contract type where parent contract does not have any child contract with a status of 'Pending'. One major thing to note is that parent contracts can have multiple child contracts with different statuses besides Pending (ex. Parent Contract 1 can have 4 Child Contracts, each with a different status such as "Active", "In Review", "In Process,etc.)

```
select
pcon.parentcontractid,
count(ccon.childcontractid)
from
tblcontract pcon,
tblcontract ccon
where
ccon.parentcontractid = pcon.parentcontractid
and ccon.contract_type = 'CHILD CONTRACT'
and pcon.contract_status in ('Active','Pending')
and pcon.group = 'Legal'
and ccon.stat_cd = 'Pending'
group by pcon.parentcontractid;
```

^^having count(ccon.childcontractid) = o results in no results, but there are examples of this situation in the database, so I have something wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I must ask - Is the join meant to join parentcontractid to itself?

Comment: @JaazCole really should appear as the below, all contracts are in the contract table and the only "child" identifier is if there is both a parent contract id and a contract id:
    ccon.parentcontractid = pcon.contractid

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using an implicit `INNER JOIN`, you will never get 0 as a count, because those records will not be included. What you are looking for is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. This preserves all the rows from the 'left' table.

This query should do the trick:

```
SELECT pcon.parentcontractid, COUNT(ccon.childcontractid)
FROM tblcontract pcon
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblcontract ccon
ON ccon.parentcontractid = pcon.parentcontractid 
AND ccon.contract_type = 'CHILD CONTRACT'
AND ccon.stat_cd = 'Pending'
WHERE pcon.contract_status IN ('Active','Pending')
AND pcon.group = 'Legal'
GROUP BY pcon.parentcontractid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misread your post, I think you can simplify this quite a bit just by using IN or EXISTS.
Since you are getting all of the parentcontractid's anyway just...

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblcontract 
WHERE parentcontractid NOT IN(SELECT c.parentcontractid 
                          FROM tblcontract c
                          WHERE c.contract_type = 'CHILD CONTRACT' 
                             and c.stat_cd = 'Pending')
```